# How can i use nosetest to run an shell script or another python script

Tags: python, nose

[nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/)

is a test runner which extends PyUnit. Is it possible to write e.g

```
$ nosetests --with-shell myTest.py -myargs test
```

If not, then is there a plugin, or do i need to develop it myself.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What does `--with-shell` do? I don't know if it's a stock option. If it's something that you're adding, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: i expect it to run arbitrary shell commands, e.g. "ls -l" , or myPython.py whoch takes arguments itself

Comment: And what's the purpose of this? What's the difference between using nose to run these scripts and directly calling them using `myTest.py test`?

Comment: @Noufal because i want to use one tool (one command line) as a one button test start , and also while staying in nose be able to run external commands. I could do it all in a shell script, but then, my goal is to use nose as a Test Automation framework. Makes sense ? this way, i am using nose's ability to find tests and render results and run unit tests, which are already integrated with Jenkins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nose is not a general test harness. It's specifically a Python harness which runs Python unit tests.

So, while you can [write extensions](http://community.activestate.com/impatient-developers-guide-writing-python-nose-plugins) for it to execute scripts and mark them as successes or failures based on the exit status or an output string, I think it's an attempt to shoehorn the harness into doing something it's not really meant to do.

You should package your tests as Python functions or classes and then have them use a library to run external scripts the output or behaviour of which is translated into something that nose can interpret rather than extend nose to directly run scripts.

Also, I've experimented with nose a bit and found it's extension mechanism quite clumsy compared to [py.test](http://pytest.org/). You might want to give that a shot.